# Calculating value of string using array_foreach

Tags: qgis

I am relatively new to this, but I have an attribute table field (SPECIES_PR) where some fish species are delimited with a comma and I would like to evaluate each species in the string, then assign the highest value I've set among the group for each rated species (ARGR, BLTR, BRST, BURB) to a field vul.

I've gotten this far, but cannot think how I can link this to a max value expression.

[image: Attribute table]

[image]

EXPRESSION:

```
array_foreach(string_to_array("SPECIES_PR",','),
map_get(map('ARGR',1,'BLTR',1,'BRST',2,'BURB',2),@element))
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear to me. In the screenshot you presented, whicht of the four names do you want to get? Which one is the one with "max value"? Even in the expression you provided, it remains unclear based on what you assign the values to each key in the map - and which of the values you want to get. There are two keys with value 1 and again two keys with value 2: which one is the max value? Based on what criteria? Where do these values of 1 and 2 come from?

Comment: The data set is hypothetical, in a sense.  I would like to put the highest value among the group ('ARGR', 'BLTR', etc.) of values in the delimited string field SPECIES_PR.  In this case the highest value would be 2.  Honestly, though, I looked over the data and there is another value of 'NO FISH SAMPLED TO DATE'.  The best case is to assign a value of 1 for fish species codes of 'ARGR', 'BLTR', etc. in the SPECIES_PR field and a value of 0.5 for 'NO FISH SAMPLED TO DATE' in the SPECIES_PR field.  It has been difficult dealing with the multiple values in a delimited string field.  Thanks.